# DolphinDB: store results together from the same group in one column

Tags: database-design, dolphindb

```
table1 = table(10:0, ["id", "value"], [INT, STRING])
insert into table1 values((1,1,2,2,3,3), `1`2`3`4`5`6)
```

I am using DolphinDB and have a table like the following:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

and this is the table I'd like to generate:

| ID | concat |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 2 | 3,4 |
| 3 | 5,6 |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `concat` will help here:

```
select concat(string(value), ",") from table1 group by id
```